# Can general purpose compressors be used for a specific gas without modification?

Tags: thermodynamics, gas-laws

[Air compressors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_compressor) are commonly used for all sorts of purposes related to compressing air above 1 atm. My question is, could an air compressor be used for a specific gas without modification?

For example, could I use an air compressor to compress Hydrogen, Oxygen, or Nitrogen, abet at a lower pressure?

Comment: Specific gas properties have to be considered. E.g. compressed oxygen cannot come into contact with organic substances like oil or grease to avoid explosion.

Comment: And hydrogen can leak through fine openings, past compressor seals, and is *very* easy to ignite over a wide concentration ratio. Using it for H2 compression involves the Hindenburg certainty principal.

Comment: Having seen the result of using a non-oxygen-rated fitting in an oxygen line (potentially mislabeled by the supplier!), extreme caution and care is needed. Do not use any equipment outside of its instructions and labeling. Pressurized hydrogen has potential excitement written over it as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, without further specifics. Assuming you mean a modest size reciprocal type. As commented, there are special consideration for primarily hydrogen or oxygen, and of course if there are specific corrodents. Large recips typically have cage/disc/flutter valves. I have seen many valves because they are a problem. I remember only one type- hard 410 stainless , so they are not altered for various gases ( refineries, chem plants and pipelines pump a variety of stuff). Get information for anything extreme. One story; Motion compensator for off shore drilling; They use 2000 psi air. They operate 24 hours/day. Some lube oil gets in the piping. Rarely it can cause a detonation of the air piping ( as a detonation ,it ruptures the pipe in several places  and throws shrapnel around).

Comment: So you are saying "yes, but really no"?

Comment: Tentative "yes", depending on specifics.

Comment: Can't help, but notice you should be more careful with punctuation and capitalisation. You should edit posts to fix such errors, otherwise it's like you scribbled it in a hurry.